# a sum of one for each coprime to n that is one greater than a multiple of d

Tags: number-theory

So I've been trying to find a simpler way to deal with this sum (even just getting an asymptote would be enough).

$ \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n. \space gcd(k, n)=1. \space d|k-1. }  1   $

Where d is an arbitrary constant and n is natural.

I've tried using the fact that

$\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n. \space gcd(k, m)=1} 1=n\frac {\phi(m)} {m}+O\left( 2^{\omega(m)} \right) $

But I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: I had a look at this and imagine the result will be quite similar to the last equation you wrote. I suspect that this is a problem that expects you to adapt the proof of that estimate to the new situation, in which instead of looking at the sequence $1, 2, \dots, n$, you need to look at the part of the arithmetic sequence $1, 1 + d, 1 + 2d, \dots$ that is $\leq n$. You need to note that the elements of this sequence are relatively prime to any prime dividing $d$.